# Find and append an string in json file using jq

Tags: json, linux, shell, sed, jq

I've a Json file `meta.json` with the below content and I want to do find and append operation in the below json file using *jq filter*. For example the below json value of `name` is `demo` so, append an string to it like `-test` so the final value will be `demo-test`

```
{
  "version": "2.2.0",
  "vname": "tf",
  "data": {
    "name": "demo",
    "udn": {
      "description": "The `main` tf in this template creates a resource`. "
    }
  }
}
```

The updated json file should contain the data like below

```
{
  "version": "2.2.0",
  "vname": "tf",
  "data": {
    "name": "demo-test",
    "udn": {
      "description": "The `main` tf in this template creates a resource`. "
    }
  }
}
```

Does JQ filter supports this? how we can do this?

Comment: So you want to append `-test` to the `name` inside `data` ? `.data.name += "-test"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `jq`

```
$ jq '.data.name |= . + "-test"' meta.json
{
  "version": "2.2.0",
  "vname": "tf",
  "data": {
    "name": "demo-test",
    "udn": {
      "description": "The `main` tf in this template creates a resource`. "
    }
  }
}
```

Using `sed`

```
$ sed '/\<name\>/s/[[:punct:]]\+$/-test&/' meta.json
{
  "version": "2.2.0",
  "vname": "tf",
  "data": {
    "name": "demo-test",
    "udn": {
      "description": "The `main` tf in this template creates a resource`. "
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `|= . +` can be written as `+=`, thus `.data.name += "-test"` will work the same.

Comment: @pmf Thanks. Still new to `jq` so good to know.